# Como crear una variable que cataloge en dos grupos los valores que toma otra variable en MATLAB

Tags: loops, matlab

Tengo una variable "variante" que toma los siguientes valores: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 y 6.

Lo que necesito hacer, es una variable nueva llamada `amistad` que tome valor 1 para los casos en los que la `variante` toma valor 1, 3, 5 y que tome valor 2 para los casos en los que `variante` toma valor 2, 4 y 6.

Intente el siguiente loop:

```
amistad= amistad(296,1)
for i=1:296 
    i= variante 
    if i== 1||3||5
        amistad(i) = 1
    if i == 2||4||6
        amistad(i)= 2
    end
```

Pero en ningún momento me crea la variable `amistad` y no se si esta es la manera correcta de hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

A reserva de que haya algunas cuestiones omitidas, te comento los siguientes puntos a considerar:

Entiendo que la variable `amistad` es un vector de 296x1 elementos, luego, es incorrecto inicializar de esa forma la variable `amistad`, dado que no la tienes definida previamente (claro, a menos que dispongas de una definición de clase o función que te retorne una matriz de esas dimensiones, lo cual desconozco ahora). Lo adecuado sería utilizar la función `zeros` para inicializar un vector de ceros que irás rellenando conforme sea necesario, es decir:

```
amistad = zeros(296,1);
```

Ahora, hay algo que me parece un tanto "inusual" en tú código: ¿por qué modificas "manualmente" el valor de la variable **i**?. Normalmente una variable de ciclo no la modificas, la puedes usar para operar con ella, pero no modificarla. En esta caso el valor de tu variable de ciclo será siempre la misma: el asignado a **variante**, y por ende estarás "rellenando" siempre la misma posición, lo cual es *absurdo* dado que para ello no necesitas un bucle.

Otro punto que deberías revisar es respecto a tu condición `if`, ¿no sería mejor verificar si el número en cuestión es par o impar, en lugar de colocar de manera explícita los números?.